Splitting a HTML document for an LLM with limited token size
Scenario:
I am trying to make modifications to a HTML file based on some user/dev feedback. I want to introduce a layer in my CI/CD pipeline that makes modifications to the html build of my project before it is deployed. Feedback can be something like "make sure images are lazy loaded" (just an example).
Problem:

I cannot pass the entire HTML document, because the LLM has a maximum allowed token size.
Context window is 128k and output tokens is ~16k. I stuck to making each chunk at most 15k tokens because I expect the LLM to return a modified chunk if any changes or the original chunk if no changes are made. 15k for the chunk allows the rest of the prompt to fit into the original 16k output token limit.
Because of this I implemented a script to split the HTML file into independent chunks
using a depth-first approach, but I keep getting repeated elements between chunks.
I would be open to the idea of the LLM itself assessing what portions of the HTML tree a user's comment relate to and then returning modifications for just those related sections instead of having to return both modified and unmodified sections in my current example, but the LLM would still need knowledge of the entire tree. Hence why coming up with an ideal chunking strategy is paramount for me.
Please note that the HTML files I am considering are at least 248k tokens each.

Expectation:

That my script splits the html file into chunks of a maximum of 15k tokens, with non-repeated sections.
That it is split in a way that I can join together the outputs of all chunks and create a modified html file.
PS: This is something I am exploring, if you have any better approaches, I would be open to those too.

Script for chunking:
 def split_html_into_chunks(self, node, token_limit):
        chunks = []
        current_chunk = []
        current_tokens = 0

        def dfs(element):
            nonlocal current_chunk, current_tokens

            # Get text and token count of the element
            if isinstance(element, str):
                text = element.strip()
                tokens = self.estimate_tokens(text)
            else:
                text = str(element)
                tokens = self.estimate_tokens(text)

            # If a single element exceeds the token limit, break it down further
            if tokens > token_limit:
                if hasattr(element, 'children'):
                    for child in element.children:
                        dfs(child)
                return

            # If adding this element exceeds the limit, finalize the current chunk
            if current_tokens + tokens > token_limit:
                chunks.append(current_chunk)
                current_chunk = []
                current_tokens = 0

            # Add element to current chunk
            current_chunk.append(element)
            current_tokens += tokens

            # Recurse into children if it's a Tag
            if hasattr(element, 'children'):
                for child in element.children:
                    dfs(child)

        # Start DFS traversal
        dfs(node)

        # Add the last chunk if not empty
        if current_chunk:
            chunks.append(current_chunk)

        return chunks

Script for modifying and joining back:
    def modify_html_with_llm(self, audit_issue):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.html, 'html.parser')
        
        # Split the entire document into chunks
        html_chunks = self.split_html_into_chunks(soup, TOKEN_LIMIT)

        serialized_chunks = self.serialize_chunks(html_chunks)
      
        # Iterate through each chunk, send it to the LLM, and replace it in the soup
        modified_chunks = []
        chunk_json = {}
        for i, chunk in enumerate(serialized_chunks):
            print(f"Processing chunk {i+1}/{len(serialized_chunks)} with {self.estimate_tokens(chunk)} tokens...")
            modified_chunk = self.send_to_llm(chunk, audit_issue)
            modified_chunks.append(modified_chunk)

        # Join all modified parts back into the original structure
        modified_html = ''.join(modified_chunks)

Prompt:
        You are a web developer. 
        Based on the following user optimization feedback {feedback},
        please modify this HTML code to resolve the performance issue:

        Return the modified HTML code alone, 
        making only necessary changes for the given feedback. 
        If no changes are possible, return the original code.

        The original HTML code is as follows:

        {html_part}


I highly recommend not allowing the LLM to push changes without you accepting them first. Not sure based on your wording in your original message.

oh yeah @jrgilman, for sure it's not going to be pushing changes directly into production. This is just a proof of concept. Even if a dev is going to look over the changes, I am still faced with the challenge of splitting/chunking the html file

Are you sure you cannot do these basic checks with bunch of IFs and some regex? Adding AI to do static analysis of code sounds like a huge overengineering. And output of AI cannot be used without human verification anyway. AI can produce mistakes and hallucinate.

Bro I am at same stage. I want to make LLM understand HTML and CSS both but as we know that HTML is too complex to make LLM understand (that parent and child hierarchy thing). Hence with that LLM don't understand HTML at all we can only proceed with some structured form where it scrap the content which we don't required for our use case (website - https://jina.ai/reader/). So I am stuck at same stage. You can try gemini-pro-002 model it have 2 million context window. Even I am facing same issue. There is something in Langchain too if it helps to you - https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/document_loader_html/
